# Can't run Nodejs server with few TS files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to implement Typescript in an existing Nodejs project. I can't convert the whole project at once as its coupled with git submodules so I am just trying to convert the route files in api folder into TS for once.
My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",                          
    "module": "ES6",                  
    "lib": ["es6"],                     
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "outDir": "dist",                          
    "rootDir": ".",
    "strict": true,         
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution":"node",
  },
}
```

I use imports, I have `"type": "module"` in package.json. To run the server I am using `"concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\""`

I am not sure why but I am getting below error

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for file-path/abc.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing the [`allowImportingTsExtensions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#allowImportingTsExtensions) compiler option

But more likely is that you try to import a .TS file *from a .JS file* which does not work, because `node` can't just import .TS files

The correct way would be importing `file-path/abc.JS` so it's imports the compiled file and not the original

Try setting `moduleResolution` to `node16`, then it'll force you to use `.js` extensions everywhere

---

If you don't mind using additional software, I recommend using https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx for development, which does not need compilation and has a builtin watcher
With it that import would "just work".

Comment: Basically my index(main server) file is in .js and other files are in the .ts extension except the git submodule files. I think I saw an example somewhere like this.